# How can we use abs() on every element inside braces of sum

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where I need to filter out those records in which few NUMBER columns have zero as its value.

Say record 1 contains: c1_amount= 5, c2_amount=-2, c3_amount=-3 and other columns are having zeroes.
Here, the following code fails, as it will filter out the records which is not exactly what I want because 3 columns has non zero values but after sum resulting zero.

```
Select * from table where
( C1_amount+
  C2_amount+
  .
  .
  .
  C50_amount) <>0;
```

I am little concerned about performance. That is the reason why I neither want to use abs() on all 50 column nor check every column <> 0.

Comment: You mean that you need select only records where any of C1_amount...C50_amount is not zero?

Comment: Yes you got it right, i have more then 50 such amount columns. Where anyone is not zero need to be picked the entire record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 
  decode(c1_amount,0,0,1)+decode(c2_amount,0,0,1)+..
      ..+decode(c50_amount,0,0,1)>0
```

or use `ALL`

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE
0!=ANY(c1_amount,...,c50_amount)
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question, many columns would have zero, very few of them would have the non zero values. Your code doesn't work few a single column is having zero value

Comment: In my humble opinion first `select` return records with at least one non-zero field. 
Indeed in second select is a typo. In this case 'ALL' means 'ANY'